Object to closed question
My question has been closed due to missing clarity, but there are people active it in the comments who clearly understood my question and are posting comments that would be valid accepted answers.
Can I or the commentors or someone else object to the closing, so that the commentors are able to post their answer and me to accept it?
I have seen that I could make adjustments to the question to have the closing be reevaluated, but I don't think that would be neccessary as, again, people in the comments have correctly interpreted the question.

The post ins question: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/104682/use-of-graphic-visualisation-of-licensed-song

3 people including a moderator thought it was unclear enough to vote to close
You should take that feedback as feedback. Comments from other users are not the appropriate place to workshop a question; if you have enough reputation you can spin up a chat room for that.
Look at the guidance and critically apply it to your question. I would be very, very surprised if your question is impossible to improve.
Editing the question gets it put in the reopen queue
More people will see it. That means more opportunities to get the 5 reopen votes you need.

Note that even if edited the question might trigger the "Request for specific legal advice" closure, due to wording.
